# Need tricky algebraic simplification problems for practicing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some tricky algebra simplification problems. Something like this:
$\cfrac {a + 27}{\sqrt[3]{a} + 3}$
(this might not look like tricky to you, but I could not simplify it...). I need to practice them, but I cannot find any decent set of problems online.

PS: I know how to solve $\cfrac {a + 27}{\sqrt[3]{a} + 3}$ (already), I just provided it as an example.

I am looking for simplification problems to practice!

Thanks!

Comment: Write it as $\frac{b^3+27}{b+3}$ where $b=\sqrt[3]a$ and think long division.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know how to solve it. I mean, I looked up the solution. And now I am looking for simplification problem examples to practice!

Comment: What did you see when you googled for "algebraic simplification problems"?

Comment: @Χpẘ easy problems...

Comment: I'd say that knowing how to solve something and knowing how to look up the solution are rather different things.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That is exactly why I am asking for other problems to practice my skills...

Comment: look up 'simplifying rational expressions practice'

Comment: Try this: $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)(x-f)(x-g)...(x-y)(x-z)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x+27}{x^{1/3}+3}=\frac{x^{3/3}+3^3}{x^{1/3}+3}=\frac{(x^{1/3}+3)(x^{2/3}+3x^{1/3}+9)}{x^{1/3}+3}=x^{2/3}+3x^{1/3}+9$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP. He's looking for problems to practice with.

Comment: http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/rational/simplifying/simplifying_practice.html

Answer (score 0):

1)   $\frac{a^5 - b^5}{a-b}$

2) $\frac{a^5 + b^5}{a+b}$

3) $\frac{x^5+48x^4+779x^3+4535x^2+4488x+3757}{x^2+34x+289}$

4) $x^3 + x^2 + 4x +4$

5) $x^5−3x^4+45x^3+−135x^2+324x−972$

TOPICS: Formulas for factoring, synthetic division, factoring by grouping.

I'll edit and add more if I remember anything else that's nice, or if you has some formula that you're not very clear on.

Comment: are you trying to say that #3 is nice? because omg...

Comment: Well, I'd hate to spoil it for him, but you can get it down to a cubic. That's about all @OP should do unless he wants me to teach him how to solve a cubic :).

Comment: well, I don't doubt that you can, since 5-2=3, but I think the large numbers might discourage @OP from completing it and force him to give up.

Comment: True. HINT: Synthetic division is a very good friend, especially since I told you this can be simplified.